# create a table if not exist in sqlite3 python using variable

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, pycharm

I am trying to create a new table in sqlite3 database for each name  I get from my entry widget in tkinter
i don't know how to do it
[image: here username is variable for entry widget get]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

1. The `CREATE TABLE` syntax doesn't have a `VALUES` clause. You just put the table name there.
2. Placeholders can only be used where an expression is allowed, they can't be used to substitute table and column names.

You have to use string formatting.

```
cursr.execute(f"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {username} (
    site_name TEXT,
    user_id TEXT,
    user_password TEXT)""")
```

As an aside, creating a table for each user is probably a poor design. Dynamic data should be in table data, not table and column names. Why not just have a single table `user_sites` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user_sites (
    username TEXT,
    site_name TEXT,
    user_id TEXT,
    user_password TEXT)
```

Comment: actually i am  creating password storage app where u save the user name ,table gets created and when you log in using that name it opens that table data for you

Comment: It could just select all the records in the table `WHERE username = ?`

Comment: i am not getting exe file in dist folder after converting main.py into exe using pyinstaller

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about pyinstaller.